# Typescript promise issue with command chain

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, async-await

Im trying to do a command chain operation in Typescript (Im not much familiar with TS) and Im getting an issue with the execution of the code. Basically the second command executes first. I would like the second one waits for the first.

This is my Orchestrator class:

```js
export class Orchestrator {
  private commands: Command[] = [];

  withCommand(cmd: Command): this {
    this.commands.push(cmd);
    return this;
  }

  async run(): Promise<void> {
    for (const cmd of this.commands) {
      try {
        await cmd.execute();
      } catch (error) {
        throw error;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the index:

```js
import { Orchestrator } from "./orchestrator";

export class Main {
  private orchestrator: Orchestrator;

  constructor() {
    this.orchestrator = new Orchestrator();
  }

  async run() {
    try {
      await this.orchestrator
        .withCommand(new FirstCommand())
        .withCommand(new SecondCommand())
        .run();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`Orchestration failed: ${error}`);
      process.exit(1);
    }
  }
}
```

for First and Second commands I have this code:

```js
export class FirstCommand implements Command {
  async execute(): Promise<void> {
    const scriptPath = join(__dirname, "myscript.sh");
    const bashRunner: BashRunner = new BashRunner();
    await bashRunner.run(scriptPath);
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: How do you know that the second command runs first if they both do the same?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed...

the `BashRunner` was the problem. There was an issue the way I used the resolve().
Now the code works and looks like:

```js
import { spawn } from "child_process";

export class BashRunner {
  async run(filepath: string): Promise<void> {
    const child = spawn("bash", [filepath]);

    return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
      child.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
        console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
      });

      child.stderr.on("data", (data) => {
        console.log(`stderr: ${data}`);
      });

      child.on("exit", (code) => {
        if (code === 0) {
          resolve();
        } else {
          reject(new Error(`Export script exited with code ${code}`));
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Thanks @konrad